# Having trouble with Jenkins Credentials binding and Python Builder

Tags: python, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

Good morning,

I am having trouble setting up Jenkins Credentials Bindings and passing them to a python builder plugin.

The plugin it self allows you to run python scripts that you write in Jenkins, I have tried things like ${} 
$Var

I am new to python and Jenkins, I just am wanting to pass the password for an account into the script using the binding. Any help would be great. Thanks

Comment: Please post code sample from your pipeline so that members can help you better.